# Security Exception When Writing File On Hosting Server

Tags: asp.net, security, file, permissions

My ASP.NET web application writes to a local file. On my dev server it works fine, but when hosted I get a Security Exception at the line of code which writes.

[image]

I googled around and found explanations regarding trust level the web.config. Does changing the trust level have any negative impact on security? Is this the only way to resolve this?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about it, in a hosting environment, if was allowed to write outside the root site directory, everone could write data inside the directory of another site. Well, this was a major security problem and Microsoft pressed every hosting provider to change trust level to [`Medium Trust`](https://web.archive.org/web/20210525032809/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/100307-1.aspx) for this specific reason. Of course your dev machine could be changed to trust everything you like, but this will never happen in a real hosting scenario

Comment: So obviously this is not a good approach. Know of any alternatives?

Comment: Yes, write inside your site. See [HttpUtility.MapPath](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/100307-1.aspx)

Comment: Needs to be local. My app saves a file to local path and user's desktop app picks it up from local.

Comment: But your asp.net site has its own root directory. For example `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite`. Create a directory here (MyXMLData for example) then use HttpUtility.MapPath("/MyXMLData") to get the full path name where you can store your data. without permission problems

Comment: I have no problem writing to my server, but there's a 3rd part desktop app on user's machine that needs to pick up my files, but can only look in *local* directory.

Comment: So your code writes on the server, but the file need to be on the client machine. You need to download and ask the user where he/she wants to save it.

Comment: This is meant to be an automated process, and wouldn't work for the user to manually save each one. Looks like I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You should contact your hosting company, it's definitely a trust issue and not something you can fix.  You could however find another hosting company that supports Medium Trust +  level.